# In web forms do the global class variables and any statements get executed before page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In this example:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    Directory finalDirectory = null;  
    static FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"c:\sw.txt");
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, f);


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Attributes["style"] = "padding-top: 2px;";

    }
}
//more code
```

Will the instances of `finalDirectory` and `Analyzer` be instantiated before anything else happens such as before `Page_load` takes place and before I click any buttons on my page?

Comment: Ask yourself, what would happen if `_Default` were just a normal class, and not a page?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but you may want to take a look at the page life cycle in ASP.NET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It would load all of the global variables before performing operations in the main() function?

Answer (score 0):

`_Default` is a class, so it has a constructor which is the first thing that is executed when creating instance of this class. So to answer your questions the variables will be initialized before `Page_Load` is executed.